# How to make SQL Server CONTAINS to use a reference table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to perform an update on a table with `FULLTEXT INDEX` on the `Plants_Hystory` column.

```
SELECT Plants_Hystory, Species, Colour 
FROM Plants   

UPDATE Plants
SET Colour = 'White'
WHERE CONTAINS(Plants_Hystory, 'Anthemis punctata')
```

'Anthemis punctata' is the latin name of a plant. I have a very long list of Plant Latin Names to use for scanning the `Plants_Hystory` column and if present update the column termed `Colour`.

Is it possible to make `CONTAINS` to refer to another table containing all Plant Latin Names (`select Names from Plant_Latin_Names`)?

I know the script below will not work, it is just to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
UPDATE Plants
SET Colour = 'White'
WHERE CONTAINS(Plants_Hystory,'select Names from Plant_Latin_Names')
```

Thank you!

Comment: What column should we use to relate records in `Plants` to those in `Plant_Latin_Names`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an update, set, from like below.

```
update
    Plants
set
    Colour = PLN.Colour
from
    Plants as P
    join Plant_Latin_Names as PLN
        on P.Plants_Hystory = PLN.Name
```

Now, I don't know what your tables look like, so here's my full testing and results.

```
create table #TempPlantNames
(
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    Color varchar(50) not null
)

insert into 
    #TempPlantNames
values
    ('Anthemis punctata', 'White'),
    ('Anthemis punctato', 'Black')

create table #TempPlants
(
    Hystory varchar(50) not null,
    Species varchar(50) not null,
    Colour varchar(50) not null
)

insert into #TempPlants
values 
    ('Anthemis punctata', 'Flower', 'unknown'),
    ('Anthemis punctato', 'Flower', 'unknown')

select
    * 
from
    #TempPlants

update
    #TempPlants
set
    [Colour] = tPN.Color
from
    #TempPlantNames as tPN
    join #TempPlants as tP
        on tPN.Name = tP.Hystory

select
    * 
from
    #TempPlants

drop table #TempPlantNames
drop table #TempPlants
```

---

Before

```
    Hystory             Species Colour
    Anthemis punctata   Flower  unknown
    Anthemis punctato   Flower  unknown
```

After

```
    Hystory             Species Colour
    Anthemis punctata   Flower  White
    Anthemis punctato   Flower  Black
```

---

Update

If there is no direct relationship between Plants and Plant_Latin_Names, you can use CHARINDEX to match the tables (below), but if there is not a 1:1 match between the two tables (multiple Latin names apply to one plant or vice versa), you are in trouble. I would test this a lot before utilizing it to make sure you don't mess up some data. Maybe you can add another comparison between two other columns of these tables.

```
update
    #TempPlants
set
    [Colour] = tPN.Color
from
    #TempPlantNames as tPN
    join #TempPlants as tP
        on charindex(tP.Hystory, tPN.Name) > 0
```

Comment: Hi Adam.stowe, thank you for your input, the problem is that Plants_Hystory column contains free text (example: of the name of the genus was followed by a single specific epithetterms and illustrated the different parts of the Anthemis punctata plant which was first discovered in...) So i cannot use join and like will take too long to scan throw all the words. The only way is through CONTAINS. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Updated the answer to keep things together